# SQL How to extract numbers from a string?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am working on a query in SQL that should be able to extract numbers on different/random lenght from the beginning of the text string.

Text string: 666 devils number is not 8888.
Text string: 12345 devils number is my PIN, that is 6666.

I want to get in a column

```
666
12345
```

Comment: Are you wanting the numbers to be returned *as strings*, or *as numbers*?

Comment: I guess is does not matter - I need it for Excel output.

Comment: `regexp_substr(t_column, '^\d+')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a combination of `Substr` & `instr`

```
SELECT Substr (textstring, 1,instr(textstring,' ') - 1) AS Output
FROM yourtable
```

Result:

```
OUTPUT
666
12345
```

Use this if you have text at the beginning e.g. `aa12345 devils number is my PIN, that is 6666.` as it utilises the `REGEXP_REPLACE` function.

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(Substr (textstring, 1,instr(textstring,' ') - 1), '[[:alpha:]]','') AS Output
FROM yourtable
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8edc9/1/0

Answer (score 0):

This version utilizes a regular expression which gives you the first number whether or not it's preceded by text and does not use the ghastly nested instr/substr calls:

```
SQL> with tbl(data) as (
     select '666 devils number is not 8888' from dual
     union
     select '12345 devils number is my PIN, that is 6666' from dual
     union
     select 'aa12345 devils number is my PIN, that is 6666' from dual
   )
   select regexp_substr(data, '^\D*(\d+) ', 1, 1, null, 1) first_nbr
   from tbl;

FIRST_NBR
---------------------------------------------
12345
666
12345

SQL>
```